# Does memorylessness imply independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be independent $Expo(\lambda)$ r.v.s and $M = max(X,Y)$. Show that $M$ has the same distribution as $X+Y/2$.

The answer is below. It seems that what the solution is saying is that "memoryless means we're starting over, so the present is independent of the past, because the past doesn't exist since we're 'restarting.'" Which makes me wonder whether memorylessness implies independence of the "past"

[image]

Comment: Memorylessness of the underlying arrival process can be translated as the Markov property, which in turn implies the strong Markov property. Both properties tells that given the present, the past and future are independent (with the former only applying to "present at a fixed time" and the latter to "present at a stopping time").

Comment: @SangchulLee What do you mean by "implies the strong Markov property?"  I agree that the arrival process has the strong Markov property, but the Markov property does not in general imply the strong Markov property

Comment: @JeanMarie It would appear that the question asker does indeed mean $X+\frac 12 Y$ rather than $(X+Y)/2$.

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you !

Comment: @user6247850, I absolutely agree with you that (weak) MP in general do not imply SMP. In that comment, I was considering any finite-state continuous-time Markov chain underlying OP's question.